# WSL2: Mount a device in windows as a device file in linux

Tags: linux, wsl2, devicesanddrives

I am in a position where I need to access a drive from WSL. Unfortunately, I need to format it with a specific filesystem (ext4) on WSL since windows doesn't support that filesystem. As a result, I need to be able to have a device file to reference when formatting the disk on WSL. While I can mount a drive to a folder using `sudo mount -t drvfs e: /mnt/edrive`, I cannot seem to find any information about how to create a device file for a drive mounted in Windows. Is there any way that I can create a device file in WSL that references a drive mounted in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you are looking for a [new feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) that is coming in WSL, but is currently only available in Windows Insider/Preview.  Don't let the fact that the command is named `--mount` confuse the issue (although it certainly is confusing).  At least the way I read the doc (I'm not using Preview), this can create a block device in WSL from a raw, unformatted drive connected in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to attach your device, e.g. a USB-disk which appears as E:, to your Windows system and reboot.

Then restart wsl2 (WindowsTerm->Debian or whatever) and you will now see a new `/mnt/e` magically created for you :-)

Then use the command `sudo mount -t drvfs E: /mnt/e` you show above to mount that disk as a normal unix mountpoint.

Comment: OP is using _ext4_, which Windows does not support. _drvfs_ mounts are not going to work.